# Raphaël Donut chart click and unclick sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, donut-chart

I am a novice with this but I am trying to create a donut chart that has sections that scale larger when clicked and then when a different section is clicked the first section returns to the original size and the new section scales larger.

I have the chart and the scaling with the click but right now I can only get the section to go back to the original size with mouseout.

This is the code I have:

```
 p.click(function () {
            p.stop().animate({transform: "s1.1 1.1 " + cx + " " + cy}, ms, "elastic");
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms, "elastic");
        }).mouseout(function () {
            p.stop().animate({transform: ""}, ms, "elastic");
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dll416/70twey1o/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is to be able to select all of the other sectors and text labels from within the click listener function.

I've created an example which achieves what you're looking for by assigning a class to each sector and text label, and uses these classes to perform the "hide" animations: http://jsfiddle.net/8opkfpxs/4/

**Setting up the classes:**

```
p.node.setAttribute('class', 'sector');
txt.node.setAttribute('class', 'sectorTxt');
```

**Accessing the classes when a sector is clicked:**

```
        p.click(function (e) {
            donut.forEach(function(element) {
                var className = element.node.getAttribute('class');
                if(className === 'sector') {
                    element.stop().animate({transform: ""}, ms, "elastic");   
                }
                else if(className === 'sectorTxt') {
                    element.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);   
                }
            });
            p.stop().animate({transform: "s1.1 1.1 " + cx + " " + cy}, ms, "elastic");
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms, "elastic");                    
        });
```

You'll also need to store the Raphael context in a variable - `donut` in the example above - to be able to use the `forEach` function within the click listener.

```
donut = Raphael("holder", 700, 700).donutChart(350, 350, 200, 50, values, labels, "#fff");
```

Comment: This works great. I've got a couple further questions, How would I add a hover state also. I want the hover to change the fill and and revert to original fill when not hovered and then when clicked the section scales.

Comment: Also I now have the text over the section and the click doesn't work if the mouse is over the text - it only works if you click in a location where there is no text. Is there a way to make the click happen whether or not you are on the text?  [Here is the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dll416/jfhgna1y/7/)

Comment: @Dab0416 you can add a hover state by using the mouseover and mouseout event listeners. As for the text, you'll need to hook up your click event to this too (as well as hover events if you add them) and find the associated sector to animate. You're probably going to need to find the index of the text and use that to search through the array of sectors with the class "sector".

Comment: One final question - is there a way to make the chart load with one section already expanded?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mouseOut function and before appling the transform onClick reset the whole set transformations and attribute changes, also separate the chart set into 2.
I also recommend you draw each chart inside an array.

I just changed these lines:

```
chartTxt = this.set(),
chart = this.set();
```

and

```
p.click(function () {
    chart.transform("");
    chartTxt.attr({opacity: 0});
    this.stop().animate({transform: "s1.1 1.1 " + cx + " " + cy}, ms, "elastic");
    txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms, "elastic");
});
```

and

```
chart.push(p);
chartTxt.push(txt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/m4tcr4tg/

Comment: This one works too. And I like it because it is more understandable to a newbie like me but I accepted the other answer because when testing this one I noticed that you if click the different sections fast enough you can make it so that two sections are highlighted at the same time and that doesn't work for my purposes. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: It's ok, I was just trying to answer your question **Raphaël Donut chart click and unclick sections** as simple as I could, as I don't know of the purpose of your chart. The best solution for you may well be the opposite of what I suggested. As a footnote remember that you can control inline svg with css (fill, strokes, over and out, etc) and following the code you wrote after Athms answer, you should try to put the button and the text inside the same set or draw invisible buttons on top of the animation.

Comment: Ah! I put the hover in with css :hover and I added an invisible chart on top of the original one and assigned the click function to it. Thanks for the tips!